configure nav2 to perform only robot navigation without camera or lidar
First of all I'm new to using ROS2 (humble) and NAV2. I'm developing a differential robot project with only IMU and incremental encoders and I need to use only the navigation part of nav2 for the robot to move from point A to point B. My simulated robot publishes the odometry in /odom and the tfs in /tf correctly, but I need help to use only the navigation part, I tried to use nav2_bringup but it asks me for a map, just like nav2_navigation, I appreciate any help.
